# Difference between "invest in" and "invest into"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, differences, prepositions

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Difference between “in” and “into”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18144/difference-between-in-and-into)
>   [When should “into” be used rather than “in to,” and vice versa?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/125/when-should-into-be-used-rather-than-in-to-and-vice-versa)

> Since solar power is theoretically the most efficient energy source on earth, shouldn't we invest more **in** harnessing it?

As I was writing the sentence above, I became uncertain as to whether I should write **in** or **into**, and thereby doubted whether I really understood the difference. Please explain.

Comment: it's actually not a duplicate of the above. If you inspected the link, you'd see that the question itself is a dupe referring to the differences between "into" and "in to." That's NOT my question.

Comment: The difference betweeen _in_ and _into_ has definitely been covered by other questions. If not in the above links then maybe here: _[Classify into 4 categories or in 4 categories?](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/5519/5822)_ If you are asking more about _invest in_ vs. _invest into_, maybe you could change your title.

Comment: @Anderson: I changed the title so as to make it sound like less of a dupe.

Comment: @drm65 while my question specific to invest, I still want to know the generic differences and exceptions.

Comment: this is a dupe of "difference between in and into". however, that one was marked as a dupe of "into vs. in to", which it was not. so might as well leave this one up.

Comment: @Anderson: Did you remember [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/q/30633/10041) you asked earlier?  See the first comment under @FumbleFingers' 18-vote answer

Comment: Maybe this question was a dupe at the time but it's not now. I was about to ask a similar question specifically about *invest* as lately I've been hearing *invest into* on YouTube a lot but my whole life I've only ever known *invest in* until now.

Answer (score 4):

We always use *invest in something* and not *invest into something*. Checking both [CALD](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/invest) and [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/invest) shows no usage of *invest into*, though the latter lists *invests on*.

Comment: Not exactly. We *usually* say 'invest in*, but *invest into* isn't unknown. For some reason, the *into* form is more likely to be used when the subject is a diversity (but even then, *in* is most common).

Comment: *Invest into* has become popular with the younger generation. I'm seeing it used all over the place on YouTube, at least by American and Australian English speakers. I'm not sure about UK English yet.

Comment: Here's a very typical usage from an Australian English speaking YouTube channel: https://youtu.be/ITvXlax4ZXk?t=453

Answer (score 4):

The following Ngram indicates that "invest in" occurs nearly 400 times more frequently than "invest into".  Personally, I have always heard "invest in", never "invest into".

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=invest+into%2Cinvest+in&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Since usage ultimately defines language, I would not tend to fight "invest in" merely because of the current definition of "in".  There are many examples of words having different meanings in different contexts; "in" is one of them.

Answer (score -3):

I hope you will be able to see their differences from their meanings:

*Into*:

> –preposition
>   1.
>   to the inside of; in  toward: He walked into the room. The train chugged into the station.
>   2.
>   toward or in  the direction of: going into town.
>   3.
>   to  a point of contact with; against: backed into a parked car.

*In*:

> –preposition
>   1.
>   (used to indicate inclusion within space, a place, or limits): walking in the park.
>   2.
>   (used to indicate inclusion within something abstract or immaterial): in politics; in the autumn.
>   3.
>   (used to indicate inclusion within or occurrence during a period or limit of time): in ancient times; a task done in ten minutes.

*In* is used to indicate inclusion within; *into* is used when there is movement.

Comment: Which means, in my example, *into* is correct, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, definitely.

Comment: Your conviction is dubious (and probably invalid)based on above comments and the other post.

Comment: I disagree. Think of it like this "we must invest more *money* into harnessing *solar power*." Is that clearer? This sentence is stating that more money has to be "put into" harnessing solar power.

Comment: Your conclusion is invalid. As drm65 shows, "invest in" is much more common than "invest into". If the dictionary implies otherwise, the dictionary is incomplete. This is unsurprising, particularly in the case of prepositions.